# I can not run my Flutter app on emulator or simulator using android studio

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When I run my flutter app on android emulator or ios simulator it gives me that error,

```
ideviceinfo returned an error:
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -21
```

Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package. The repository from which the
'flutter' tool is currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: /Users/mac/development/flutter
  previous reference  : /Users/mac/Downloads/flutter
This can happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please check your system path to verify that you are running the expected version (run 'flutter
--version' to see which flutter is on your path).

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G3025, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.1.8 at /Users/mac/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 985ccb6d14 (2 months ago), 2019-01-08 13:45:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 7112b72cc2
    • Dart version 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    ✗ Verify that all connected devices have been paired with this computer in Xcode.
      If all devices have been paired, libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller may require updating.
      To update with Brew, run:
        brew update
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
        brew unlink usbmuxd
        brew link usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
    • ios-deploy 2.0.0
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                            • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
    • Mahmoud’s iPhone          • 25abd4a927c1747e3b5174c21b3ed931a30db41d • ios         • iOS 11.2.6
    • iPhone XR                 • A120C13F-FE08-47EF-8790-B977DB0A145A     • ios         • iOS 12.1 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: add `flutter doctor` result to your question.

Comment: i did add flutter doctor results

Comment: coming across the same issue, @SaeedHashem did you fix yours?